# How to define multiple sharedPreferences?

Tags: string, foreach, kotlin, android-edittext, sharedpreferences

I have managed to get the sharedPreferences saving values. But i don't know how to make it reference the text i am clicking on. In the `// Close Alert Window` section when i click ok to change the text. Ok dismisses alert dialog, then suppose to add the new price to list in `sharedPreferences`.

In the `putString()` if i use `putString("Price$it", input.text.toString()).apply`it doesn't appear to do anything. However if i use `"Price1"` any text i change is saved and upon reopening the app `Price1`is changed to the new price. So i know the method is working. i just have no clue how to save the particular text i am editing. I hope this makes sense. Thanks for your time.

```
// Created Private Price List
    val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("priceList", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

//Price
    (1..912).forEach {
        val id = resources.getIdentifier("Price$it", "id", packageName)
        val tv = findViewById<TextView>(id)
        tv.text = sharedPreferences.getString("Price$it","0.00")

    }

(1..912).forEach {
        val id = resources.getIdentifier("Price$it", "id", packageName)
        val tv = findViewById<TextView>(id)
        tv.setOnLongClickListener {

            //Alert Window
            val alertDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(this@MainActivity).create()
            alertDialog.setTitle("NEW PRICE")
            val input = EditText(this@MainActivity)
            //Alert Submit on Enter
            input.setOnKeyListener { v, keyCode, event ->
                if (event.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    // Input changes text
                    tv.text = input.text
                    when {
                        tv.text.startsWith("-") -> tv.setTextColor(Color.RED)
                        tv.text.startsWith("+") -> tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN)
                    else -> {
                        tv.text = "_"
                        tv.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY)
                    }
                    }
                    // Close Alert Window
                    alertDialog.dismiss()
                    // TODO Save Price Table  //THIS PART vvv
                    sharedPreferences.edit().putString("Price1", input.text.toString()).apply()
                }
                false
            }


            val lp = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
            )
            input.layoutParams = lp
            alertDialog.setView(input)
            alertDialog.show()
            return@setOnLongClickListener true

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are shadowing `it`. In your scope you are referencing the argument of `tv.setOnLongClickListener`. Specify the argument name so it's not shadowed by inner lambdas.

```
(1..912).forEach { index ->
    ...
    sharedPreferences.edit().putString("Price$index", input.text.toString()).apply()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, there is no way i would have picked up on that.